# Check Database for username and confirmation code and redirecting to a create password page

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to use a system to find a username and confirmation code and then redirect and have that user (if confirmation code matches) create a password for their account (unsure how to do just that).

I've tinkered with php for a little bit years ago, but things have changed, and I am providing the bare bones setup page for it.  I need some big time help, as I can't seem to find anything close to what I am wanting.  The register system is in a game, so it allows you to click a box, and it sends you a confirmation code in the game, which means you are registered, just need to make a PW.

So

1. First page checks for username and confirmation code (makes sure confirmation code is correct one)
2. 2nd page lets user create a password for their account and inserts it into their account.
3. 3rd page shows the account is set up, and has a basic link to log in.

This is the basic code below:(always returns a count of 0 unable to get past it)

```
    <?php
include( "config.php" );
session_start();
if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" )
{
    // username and password sent from form
    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db,$_POST['username'] );
    $myconfrimcode = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db,$_POST['confirmcode'] );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '$myusername' and confirmcode = '$myconfirmcode'";
    $result = mysqli_query( $db,$sql );
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result );
    $active = $row['active'];
    $count = mysqli_num_rows( $result );
    // If result matched $myusername and $myconfirmcode, table row must be 1 row
    if( $count == 1 )
    {
        session_register( "myusername" );
        $_SESSION['real_user'] = $myusername;
        redirect( "create.php" );
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        $error = "ERROR: Your User Name or Confirm Code is invalid<br>POST USER: ".$_POST['username']."<br>POST Confirm Code: ".$_POST['confirmcode']."<br>myusername: ".$myusername."<br>myconfirmcode: ".$myconfirmcode."<br> Result Count: ".$count;
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Account Setup Portal</title>

<style type = "text/css">
              body
{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
label
{
font-weight:
    bold;
    width:100px;
    font-size:14px;
}
.box
{
border:
#666666 solid 1px;
}
.middleDiv
{
position :
    absolute;
    width    : 300px;
    height   : 500px;
    left     : 50%;
    top      : 50%;
margin-left :
    -150px; /* half of the width  */
margin-top  :
    -250px; /* half of the height */
}
</style>

</head>

<body class="middleDiv" bgcolor = "#000000">

<div align = "center">
<div style = "width:300px; border: solid 1px #0000A0;" align = "center">
<div style = "background-color:#0000A0; color:#FDD017; padding:3px;"><b>Account Setup Portal</b></div>

<div style = "color:#FDD017; margin:30px">

<form action = "" method = "post">
<label>User Name  :</label><input style = "background-color:#6D6968;" type = "text" name = "username" class = "box"/><br/><br/>
<label>Password   :</label><input style = "background-color:#6D6968;" type = "text" name = "confirmcode" class = "box"/><br/><br/>
<input type = "submit" value = " Engage! "/><br />
</form>

<div style = "font-size:13px; font-weight: 600; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php echo $error;?></div>

</div>

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**I've tried many times to get this to work, I've not bothered on the PW create page, as I can't get this page to work correctly.  Any advice or help would be awesome, I'm reaching out to all the good folks here, in hopes you all can help me fix my problem with this system!**

(Fix was to correct a mis-spelled word, and remove the redirect link, which made this function as I needed it too!)

Comment: does your db connection work?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn  It does, I've not had problems with it, gives no errors or anything, the count is always 0.  If you have an idea of how else to check the connection, I'm all ears! :)

Comment: well first off try a simple select that should return 1 row with static values then you can confirm it will return a result

Comment: @maSTArHiAn okay, will let you know in a few

Comment: what's the php version you're using this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mis-spelled $myconfirmcode when you were defining it.

```
 $myconfrimcode = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db,$_POST['confirmcode'] );
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '$myusername' and confirmcode = '$myconfirmcode'";
```

Comment: @UsmanShahid I fixed that, now its giving me a 500 error, saying its unable to handle a request.  would this because by the redirect?

Comment: Thank you, that was part of the problem, the redirect was as well, so you have been selected the answer! :)

Comment: @JeffB4 if it's only "part" of the problem, why accept a partial answer? if something else failed, then you should make them aware of what it was. In not doing so, the question will remain unclear, IMHO anyway.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did!  Not only was it my mis-spelled word, it was the darn redirect `if( $count == 1 )
    {
        session_register( "myusername" );
        $_SESSION['real_user'] = $myusername;
        redirect( "create.php" );
        exit();
    }`